# react formik disable submit button with form validity

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using formik library for my react project. I need to disable  submit button initially when mandatory fields are empty or have any errors. I checked form status using below code.

```
const formik = useFormik(false);

        <Formik
        initialValues={!location.state ? InvoiceInitalValues : location.state}
        validationSchema={POValidation} innerRef={formRef}
        onSubmit={(form, actions, formikHelper) => {
          console.log(form);
          console.log(formRef);
          setTimeout(() => {
            saveInvoice(form, actions, formikHelper);
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
        }}
      >
        {({
          handleSubmit,
          handleChange,
          setFieldValue,
          values,
          handleReset,
          errors,
          resetForm, isSubmitting


        })
```

I console logged form status using but form is always 'isValid: True'. Please check below image.
[image]

I printed it in the html also. but always isValid is True. I need to this for disable my button

printed status

```
 <p> {formik.isValid=== true ? "True" : "False"} </p>
```

I tried below code to disable my button

```
<Button className="btn btn-primary mr-1" type="submit" disabled={!formik.isValid}>
```

Submit

Why formik form validity is always true, even mandatory fields are empty. I spent more time to solve this. still could not fix this. Anyone know to fix this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created form using [Formik](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik) component, but you are checking `isValid` on another formik instance created through [useFormik](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik) hook. That's not right.

You should use either `<Formik>` or `useFormik`.

As you have written code using Formik component. Here is how you access `isValid` property:

```
<Formik
  initialValues={!location.state ? InvoiceInitalValues : location.state}
  // ...
>
  {({
    values,
    handleChange,
    // ... 
    isValid // HERE
  }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
...
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-formik-form-o2te7?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: I tried it also. but form isValid always true. when form load it should be false and submit button should be disable.

Comment: Beautiful !!! I applied to my project. Its working well. Thanks @Ajeet

Comment: @Kumara To achieve that You can pass a validateOnMount prop in the Formik wrapper to solve that.

Comment: @Kumara <Formik validateOnMount {...props}><Form /></Formik>